# how to make remote p2p chat vb.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, tcp, tcpclient, portforwarding

How can i make a p2p chat in vb.net communicate with my friends PC at their house from my own.

i have made a LAN Chat which was fairly simple, but i really cannot figure out how to get it to connect to his pc using a public ip.

I Assume that port forwarding would be a factor in this but Im trying to make it so that port forwarding is not required to be done so the user (my friend) does not have to porforward.

The Program is comprised of text-boxes threads and the Transmission Control Protocol for the listeners/server

please help thank you very much, sorry if my English appalls you. :D

Comment: Why don't you use FaceBook? Or Skype?

Comment: because this is for a software assignment

Comment: `communicate with my friends PC at their house` ... who assigned it to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Fixed, It Was Port Forwarding Which Was Needed To Be Done,no need to Post on This Any More